# convert audio output to audio input

Tags: python, pyttsx3

I wrote a program in python to convert text into sounds, but the sounds are only output to the speakers, and I need them to be heard in the game or in voice chats, that is, to be output to the voice

I looked at many different options but none came up or were not working.